# String date to YYYY-MM-DD string format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, ssis, etl

I am working with [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) 2013, and I am using a string variable to store the date created from a file...

My problem is that I am getting the string value `Jan 25 2018 12:00:00`, and when I load the data into the database the column needs the string value `2018-01-25`. How do I convert the variable in the derived column task?

Comment: `as.character(strptime("Jan 25 2018 12:00:00","%b %d %Y"))`

Comment: I don't think `strptime` is a valid function in SSIS/SSDT/BIDS/whatever we're calling it today.

Comment: Never store a date in a database as a string. Unless you have a really good reason. What _data type_ is the column in the database? It's difficult to give a reliable answer without knowing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using a Derived Column

According to this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression):

> When a string is cast to a DT_DATE, or vice versa, the locale of the transformation is used. However, the date is in the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD, regardless of whether the locale preference uses the ISO format.

So you can simply use the following expression in a derived column:

```
SUBSTRING( (DT_STR,50, 1256)(DT_DATE)[DateColumn], 1, 10)
```

## Using a Script Component

*Assuming that `inDate` is the input column and `OutDate` is the output column*

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;


CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.outDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.inDate,"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",provider).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```